# GUI won't display buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, binary-search-tree

In this program everything compiles and it looks like I added all the buttons panels and textfields but when I run the program the main panel shows up without any of the added objects. The shutdown pop up screen displays correctly. Below is the GUI class. I have tried making the components public and it didn't change anything. The sub panel should be working properly according to this. However maybe a fresh pair of eyes can help me see something I am missing.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class BinarySearchTreeGUI {
private JFrame mainF;
private JPanel bstMain;
private JPanel sortOrder;
private JPanel numType;

JRadioButton ascendingB = new JRadioButton("Ascending");
JRadioButton descendingB = new JRadioButton("Descending");
JRadioButton integerB = new JRadioButton("Integer");
JRadioButton fractionB = new JRadioButton("Fraction");

private JButton button;
public JTextField unsortedList, sortedList;
private JLabel l1, l2;

@SuppressWarnings("OverridableMethodCallInConstructor")

BinarySearchTreeGUI() {
launchApp();
}

private void launchApp() {
createNewComponents();
setDisplayFrame();
setComponents();
setComponentsEditableVisible();
addComponents();
onShutDownRequest();
}

private ButtonAction buttonActionOnClick() {
return new ButtonAction(unsortedList);
}

private void addComponents() {
mainF.add(bstMain);
bstMain.add(button);
bstMain.add(l1);
bstMain.add(l2);
bstMain.add(sortedList);
bstMain.add(unsortedList);
buttonActionOnClick();
}

private void setComponentsEditableVisible() {
sortedList.setEditable(false);
mainF.setVisible(true);
}

private void setComponents() {
bstMain.setLayout(null);
button.setBounds(180, 160, 120, 30);
l1.setBounds(50, 15, 200, 25);
l2.setBounds(55, 90, 200, 25);
sortedList.setBounds(120, 90, 280, 25);
unsortedList.setBounds(120, 15, 280, 25);
setSubPanels();
}

private void createNewComponents() {
mainF = new JFrame("Binary Search Tree Sort");
bstMain = new JPanel();
button = new JButton("Perform Sort");
l1 = new JLabel("Original List");
l2 = new JLabel("Sorted List");
unsortedList = new JTextField();
sortedList = new JTextField();
sortOrder = new JPanel();
numType = new JPanel();
}

private void setDisplayFrame() {
mainF.setSize(550, 350);
mainF.setResizable(false);
mainF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
}

private void onShutDownRequest() {
  mainF.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
      int reply;
      reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(mainF, "Would you like  to Shutdown this Program", "Shutdown Request",  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
      if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
  });
}

private void setSubPanels() {
  createPanelSubPanel(5, "Sort Order", sortOrder, ascendingB, descendingB);
  createPanelSubPanel(260, "Numeric Type", numType, integerB, fractionB);
}

private void createPanelSubPanel(int location, String title, JPanel panel, JRadioButton ascendingB, JRadioButton descendingB) {
  panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
  panel.setBounds(location, 240, 230, 70);

  TitledBorder title1;
  title1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title);
  panel.setBorder(title1);

  ascendingB.setSelected(false);
  descendingB.setSelected(true);
  ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
  //add buttons
  bg.add(ascendingB);
  bg.add(descendingB);
  panel.add(ascendingB);
  panel.add(descendingB);
  bstMain.add(panel);
}

private class ButtonAction extends BinarySearchTree {
  ButtonAction(JTextField textField) {
    button.addActionListener((ActionEvent event) -> {
      CheckData reviewData = new CheckData();
      BinarySearchTree<String> unsortedList = new BinarySearchTree<>();
      if (integerB.isSelected()) {
        sortedList.setText(unsortedList.inOrderSort(unsortedList.root));
      }
      else {
               sortedList.setText(unsortedList.desOrderSort(unsortedList.root));
      }
    });
  }
}
}
```

Comment: They all show up when I run it, although it looks pretty poor since you didn’t use LayoutManagers.  My guess is that the `BinarySearchTreeGUI()` constructor is invoked in the main thread, or some other thread which isn’t the AWT event dispatch thread.  Nearly all Swing methods and constructors [are required to be invoked on the EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html), or they will behave unpredictably.  You can do this using the EventQueue.invokeLater method.  For example, `EventQueue.invokeLater(BinarySearchTreeGUI::new);`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make the components public as that goes against OOP principles and increases the risk of bugs in your code (increasing "coupling" and complexity)

You're currently setting the GUI visible before you've added all components, and that can lead to problems since the GUI may not be able to display components added to the JFrame after it has been displayed. Better to add everything first, and *then* set the GUI visible.

Other unrelated problems:

- You're using null layouts and `setBounds` which makes for difficult to debug and enhance GUI's, GUI's that may look poor on other platforms.
- You're gearing your GUI towards creating and displaying a JFrame, and that can often paint you into a corner, and often better flexible GUI creating is achieved by creating JPanels which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, other JPanels or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. Again, this will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding

Better still is to re-do how you're creating the GUI in a more logical fashion.

hang on....